# How to replace or remove list item

Tags: c#

I have a list with the following records:

```
List<Person> users = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person {Id= 1, Name = "Silva", IdBooks = "1,2,3,4,5,0" },
};
```

how do I remove the 0 or replace it with "" in IdBooks?

Comment: Your question asks about replacing or removing a list item, but IdBooks is not a list, it's just a single string. Are you actually asking how to remove a certain character from a string, or is IdBooks supposed to be a list of integers after all?

Comment: @Órion My IdBooks is a string inside the list with some book ids. This list was modified earlier so that the final result would be the same as shown in my example. Now I need to go to my users > IdBooks and replace the 0 with "" or simply remove the 0.

Answer (score 0):

users[0].IdBooks.Replace("0", "");

Should Remove the "0", but that depends on IdBooks, that has to be public.
And it is hardcoded, not an ideal solution

Comment: `string` does not contain a method Replace that accepts two arguments of type `string` and `string`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay you are totally right - I intended to say that about the string.Remove method, which Andreas originally described in his answer, then promptly changed to Replace.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Andreas, I'm pretty sure there is no .NET version that includes `string.Remove` that takes a string parameter. I looked at [.NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=net-6.0) docs myself, but perhaps you have some other version in mind.

Comment: One more thing about both the `Replace("0", "")` and hypothetical `Remove("0")` methods - they would also remove zeros from ids such as `10` or `105`, which is most likely not intended.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are actually asking about removing a certain character from a string after all, I'd go about it this way (I assumed you want to do it for every user in `users`:

```
foreach (user in users)
{
    var bookIds = user.IdBooks.Split(',');  // contains array of individual IDs
    var idsExceptZero = bookIds.Where(id => id != "0");
    user.IdBooks = string.Join(',', idsExceptZero)
}
```

If that answers your question, I would edit its title to reflect your actual question.

Be advised that if you're about to store those Person objects in a relational database, then storing a Person's many Books as a single string with multiple Book IDs is not very correct, as you'd be violating the atomicity principle.

To describe a many-to-many relationship in relational databases, one of the common ways to go is to use an associative table.